# buddypress remove username from autocomplete

Tags: customization, buddypress, username, autocomplete

I am using Wordpress and Buddypress and i am trying to remove or hide the username that is being displayed in the autocomplete field of messages in Buddypress. Tried some tests from [this](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/autocomplete-shows-both-names/) post and also [this](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/hide-username-in-autocomplete-send-to/) , but with no luck. Did someone run into this issue?

I was also looking around if i could just hide it with some css, but i think is not possible since the html is like that :

```
<li class="ac_event ac_over"><span id="link-username" href="#"></span>
<img src="https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/23/user-bpthumb.jpg" style="width: 15px"> &nbsp; User (<strong>U</strong>sername)</li>
```

and need to remove `(<strong>U</strong>sername)` 
I have also tried to remove or add some html span inside the native bp code

```
'<span id="%s" href="#"></span><img src="%s" style="width: 15px">   %s (%s)' . "\n",  
            esc_attr( 'link-' . $user->ID ),  
            esc_url( $user->image ),  
            esc_html( $user->name ),  
            esc_html( $user->ID )
```

but when i try to remove (%s) it just breaks the displayed result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this but note that it may not send the message:

```
'<span id="%s" href="#"></span><img src="%s" style="width: 15px">   %s %s' . "\n",  
            esc_attr( 'link-' . $user->ID ),  
            esc_url( $user->image ),  
            esc_html( $user->name ),  
            ' '
```

Or this:

```
'<span id="%s" href="#"></span><img src="%s" style="width: 15px">   %s' . "\n",  
            esc_attr( 'link-' . $user->ID ),  
            esc_url( $user->image ),  
            esc_html( $user->name )
```

Comment: thank you @shanebp for the help. both ideas return error message that there is no valid username when i try to send. Even though it removes the username , when i click on displayed name i get html wrap text in the ''send'' field <span id="link-user" href="#"></span><img src="https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/35/user-bpthumb.jpg" style="width: 15px">   User

Comment: why i can not just do  '<span id="%s" href="#"></span><img src="%s" style="width: 15px">   %s <span id="remove">(%s)</span>' ? so i cound add a span and then hide with css

Comment: Did you try the 'remove' approach?  I have no further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to solve this problem with some CSS, unfortunately there is no possibility to wrap with any html element around `(%s)` , BUT there is possibility to wrap with html the rest. So i did this

```
printf( '<span id="keep"><span id="%s" href="#"></span><img src="%s" style="width: 15px"> &nbsp; %s</span> (%s)' . "\n",
```

with out removing nothing from the original code, just adding the span 'keep' and then with the classic css `visibility:hidden;` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591995/8827124) i managed to hide it simple.